# Service loader does not locate service provider class, even though class is in same JAR file as META-INF/services

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am successfully running a C++ application that loads a JVM with a JAR file as a classpath argument.  The application then successfully uses JNI calls to execute various functions defined in .class files within this JAR file.

Included in the .jar file's directory structure is a 3rd-party set of .class files - those merged from jai_imageio.jar (these .class files, with their full directory structure, were merged into this single .jar file using Intellij IDEA).  Also included in the merged .jar file are the lines from the original jai_imageio.jar's `manifest.mf` - in particular `implementation-title` and related lines.  Also, the `meta-inf/services` folder is present, also copied from jai_imageio.jar.  The various services listed within the `services` directory look correct.

In particular, `javax.imageio.spi.ImageOutputStreamSpi` within the `meta-inf/services` folder in the .jar file contains the single line `com.sun.media.imageioimpl.stream.ChannelImageOutputStreamSpi`, and there is a class corresponding to this within the .jar file at exactly the directory indicatted by that line: `com/sun/media/imageioimpl/stream/ChannelImageOutputStreamSpi.class`.

However, when the Java code executes the following line:

```
ImageIO.write(image, "tiff", file); // Assume 'image' is a BufferedImage and 'file' is a File
```

... it throws an exception:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageOutputStreamSpi:
Provider com.sun.media.imageioimpl.stream.ChannelImageOutputStreamSpi not found
```

... even though this class **is** present within the same .jar file, as noted above.

Can somebody please explain why this error is happening, and what I should do to resolve it.

Comment: Does the same error happen without JNI involved (i.e. just calling the method normally from Java code)?

Comment: I will test this if need be, but it will be a hassle because many previous JNI calls (successfully) run that perform setup.  These are not causing problems in the sense that the standard image types `jpg`, `bmp` and `png` are successfully written to the file system (assuming the `jai_imageio` .class files are not merged).  If necessary, I will set it up and test it as you suggest, though I was hoping to resolve it without doing that.

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary to do any setup - you can just create a self-contained class with `ImageIO.write(image, "tiff", file);` in it, and try to run that class, with your jar in the classpath.

Comment: It did work when I ran a mini-application standalone from the command line.  As a result, it occurred to me to ask whether it was attempting to load the services at all, when running from the command line with the .jar in the path (not loaded through JNI).  To test, I deleted the `meta-inf\services` directory completely from my full application, and ran again.  There was no error, and the .tiff file was created successfully.  This problem is solved, thanks; but - what is the purpose of the `services`, if they're not necessary to actually use the class to write a file?  Another day.

Comment: The whole `services` thing is a bit half-baked, IMHO, an early attempt at dependency injection by Sun that didn't really work (just try it with OSGi or another context where classloader jiggery-pokery goes on).

Comment: Did you ever figure out the root cause for this? It's currently issue #72 filed against JNA, which I filed about a year ago. JNA also uses JNI, so the cause of my issue is probably the same as yours.

Comment: Problems with declaratively registered services in merged JARs are usually because one ``META-INF/services`` file from one JAR overwrites  one from another JAR.

Comment: Are you saying the `com.sun.media.imageioimpl.stream.ChannelImageOutputStreamSpi` class is embedded in your jar? I would expect that to be embedded in your `JRE` and for there to be potential classloader issues if it is on the classpath twice. Also, `META-INF/services` is a case-sensitive path, but you are showing `meta-inf/services` instead. This would cause it to fail as well.

Comment: We have experienced a similar issue accessing Hadoop classes via JNI.  We don't have a solution yet but we have at least narrowed down the problem.  Apparently only the thread that created the JVM can correctly use the service loaders. Threads attached to the VM later using AttachCurrentThread do not work correctly with the service loader.

Answer (score 3):

From this documentation
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html

"When a thread is attached to the VM, the context class loader is the bootstrap loader."

Any native thread attached to the JVM via AttachCurrentThread() gets only the bootstrap class loader, not even the system class loader.  Classes referenced by ServiceLoader will not be available unless you explicitly fix up the new thread's context class loader.

This can be done like:

```
java.lang.Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(
    java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
);
```

Comment: Oddly, this pertinent detail was omitted from current version of the JNI documentation.