# Why do subsequent jni threads return null on currentThread().getClassLoader()?

Tags: java-native-interface

I'm starting threads from c++ and calling into Java. The JVM itself has the classpath set correctly with all the necessary jars passed to -Djava.class.path.

Why would the "context class loader" ever be null in new threads?

I have this szenario:

```
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(); // null on new threads
ClassLoader currCl = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
ClassLoader jbossCl = org.jboss.remoting.InvocationResponse.class.getClassLoader();
```

In the first thread (it says "main" in Eclipse), all three objects are valid and contain classes. In all following threads `cl` is null.

Doesn't make any sense to me, if I load classes into the JVM, they should be available to every thread globally, shouldn't they?
There's also a wildly different amount of classes in currCl and jbossCl for some reason. First has ~600 and the other one has >1000

Comment: "starting threads from c++ and calling into Java" what does it mean?

Comment: Would you mind showing us HOW you create your threads in JNI code?

Answer (score 7):

We had this same issue, and it was baffling.  The first thread could load classes, but native threads attached to the JVM could not.  Your problem has the same solution as:
[Service loader does not locate service provider class, even though class is in same JAR file as META-INF/services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514495/service-loader-does-not-locate-service-provider-class-even-though-class-is-in-s/25922354#25922354)
Moderators may want to mark this as duplicate, but the question is very different-sounding.

From this documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html

"When a thread is attached to the VM, the context class loader is the bootstrap loader."

Any native thread attached to the JVM via AttachCurrentThread() gets only the bootstrap class loader, not even the system class loader. Classes cannot be loaded from new threads unless you explicitly fix up the new thread's context class loader.

This can be done like:

```
java.lang.Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(
    java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
);
```